# CloudKit Public Database TestFlight vs App Store

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, cloudkit, testflight

I have an App that is using CloudKit.  I have used the dashboard to setup a list of in-app purchase identifiers in the production public database.  My app loads these records upon launch.  I then use those in-app purchase IDs to get the in-app purchase to display to my users so they can select the purchase they would like.

This all works great when testing with TestFlight.  I have App approval from Apple now, but have not released it to the App store yet.  I wanted to test my App using a promo code to download from the App Store before making it available to the public.

The problem, is that those public database records are not reading in the version downloaded from the App store.  I am using the production CloudKit databases for both TestFlight and App Store but I only get the records when I am using TestFlight, not App Store.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any difference when WiFi vs cellular?

Comment: @agibson007 No.